# Hibernate Criteria filter by parent

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to filter objects based in some conditions or if their parent is of a specific type.

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class O {
    A a;
    long n;
}
```

I want all `O` objects where `n > 100` or `a is of type B`.

In `Criteria` what would be the `or` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Restrictions.eq("a.class", B.class)
```

I've had bugs though when a single-table inheritance type was chosen (using a discriminator), and where I had to use

```
Restrictions.eq("a.class", B.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE)
```

Note that `class` is an implicit property. You don't need to define anything special in the entity to make it work.

Comment: Restrictions.or or Restrictions.disjunction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Restrictions" type to create a criteria...

From my experience,

it should be something like below

Restrictions.ge("n", )

Sorry....don't remember the exact function name under Restrictions...You can check from the javadoc.

And for the object comparison, it's the same way except that you can use "eq" and give the object as a restriction...